# postfix opendkim DKIM-Signature and Domainkey-Signature

Tags: centos, postfix, dkim, domainkeys

Running postfix on CentOS 6 as an edge relay for a while now, so all our outgoing mail is routed through one point with `opendkim` signing the mail. This works great. I was originally using `dkim-filter/dkim-milter` (I believe) but switched to `opendkim` a couple of years back.

But one thing I've been meaning to get around to for a long time is getting the `DomainKey-Signature` header added in addition to the `DKIM-Signature`. I realise that `DomainKeys` is the older spec and is technically replaced by `DKIM` but I think there's still a reasonable number of systems that verify both (e.g.: Gmail).

Would this involve multiple milters, one for `DKIM` and another for the older `DomainKeys`?
I'm not too happy about the idea of having to maintain 2 sets of configurations and signing tables etc, as I have to add/remove relay domains reasonably frequently.

Anyone know if it's possible to add both signatures within `opendkim`?

Answer (score 0):

The DomainKeys standard was never implemented, at least not through RFC. [RFC 4870](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4870) even states at the very top:

> Status of This Memo
>
> This memo defines a Historic Document for the Internet community.
> It does not specify an Internet standard of any kind.

It was obsoleted by [RFC 4871](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4871) and both RFCs are dated May 2007.